# Uninformative error when trying to delete a custom field in Schema Builder

Tags: custom-field, schema-builder

Was trying to delete a custom field on the User table, in a Developer Pro sandbox and I got this error message. "Unable to complete the requested data change". Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this field was referenced in a custom Apex class. After removing the reference I was able to delete the field.